# Is $y\lim\limits _{n\to +\infty }x^n$ where $(0\leq x\leq 1)$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, continuity

Let
$$y=\lim _{n\to +\infty }x^n,$$ where $x\in[0,1]$. Is this function continuous or in what points is it discontinuous.

I am thinking that because multiplication of continuous functions is continuous than this function should be continuous.But the answer is that point $x=1$ is  *first kind* discontinuous point.

Comment: This is because you can rewrite the function as $f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{for }0\leq x<1\\1&\text{for }x=1\end{cases}$ and then it should be clear where the discontinuity is

Comment: Why we can write like that? $1^\infty$ isn't in indeterminate form?

Comment: $1^n = 1$ for all $n$, therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty}1^n$ is certainly $1$.

Comment: For any $x\in[0,1)$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=0$. And for $x=1$ we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}1^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1$. Thus we can rewrite the function as I have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n$$

$$n>0\implies 0^n=0\implies f(0)=0$$

$$n\ge 0\implies 1^n=1\implies f(1)=1$$

$$0<x<1\implies x^n=e^{n\ln(x)}\to 0$$

So $ f $ is defined at $ [0,1] $ by

$$f(x)=0 \text{ if } x\ne 1\text{ and } f(1)=1$$

So
$$\lim_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=0\ne f(1)$$